# git file difference from commit to a branch

Tags: git

Trying to work with jenkins to get the files changed between a commit and a branch

I can do something like

```
git diff --name-status branchName..staging
```

That works if I know the branch but jenkins gets a PR request from github and does a

```
git checkout -f 0798a6d1ea9fbc658dc946018e88dff52bb64ed5
```

To get the commit from the PR then runs all the checks. I'm wondering is there a way in git to get the files that are changed in a commit to a branch or get the branch name from the commit.

```
# git branch -a --contains 0798a6d1ea9fbc658dc946018e88dff52bb64ed5
* (no branch)
remotes/origin/pr/19/merge
```

That returns the PR so not what i'm looking for

So the rev-parse gives me

```
$ git rev-parse branchName
branchName
fatal: ambiguous argument 'branchName': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as `git diff` is concerned, a branch *is* a commit.  Specifically, a branch name resolves to the commit ID of the tip-most commit on that branch.  Try it yourself:

```
$ git rev-parse branchName
```

This should print something like `0f8c3a1278c1...` (the full 40 character SHA-1).  Repeat with `staging`, then feed these two raw commit IDs to your `git diff`:

```
$ git diff --name-status 1234567 fedcba9 # use the correct IDs
```

(Aside: note that `git diff name1..name2` is the same as `git diff name1 name2`.  The `diff` command is different from most git commands that accept ranges, in that it simply extracts the two end-points rather than selecting many commits.  I think it's clearer if you supply the two commits as two separate arguments, so that's why I did that above.)

In general, anywhere you can use a raw commit ID like this, you can use a name (branch or tag name), or a relative reference like `HEAD^` or `master~3`, and so on.  See [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) for all the different ways to direct git to a particular SHA-1.  This mostly works in both directions: where you can use a branch name, you can use the raw commit ID.

(There are a few places—including `git checkout`—where the result is a bit different.  In particular, if you give `checkout` a raw commit ID you get a "detached HEAD" rather than getting onto the branch.  With `git diff`, though, there's nothing special about a branch name.)

Comment: I added a edit for the rev-parse.. It doesn't turn up any info on a jenkins server

Comment: Oh, I think I see where your confusion comes from.  I was assuming you were running that `git diff` on *your* repo, using *your* branch-name, and was suggesting you run `git rev-parse` on *your* repo too.  Once you have the raw ID, you can use that ID on *any* repo that has the commit.  (The point here is that the *name* may change or vanish, but the raw SHA-1 is forever.)

Comment: thanks.. that works.. but that commit ID for staging will move when I merge in PRs to it.. Jenkins is the one that needs to do the work.. I'm sure I can work something out though